# Visual Studio 2019 Installer keep failing to download package for offline installer?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

I follow [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to create an offline installer for Visual Studio 2019.

I rerun the following cmd several times already:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\vslayout --lang en-US
```

But after a long time of verifying packages, it keeps giving me the error:

```
...
Total packages to download: 1
Starting 'UpdateLayout' operation
Error: Package 'Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi,version=9.3.1' failed to download from '
https://aka.ms/AA9z5w0'. WebClient download failed: The request was aborted: Cou
ld not create SSL/TLS secure channel.. Bits download failed: File not found.. Wi
nInet download failed: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012867, Message: Unkn
own error 12029, Signature: PackageId=Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi;PackageAction=Down
loadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80131500
UpdateLayout progress: 99.00%
Error: Setup completed with errors.
Error: One or more errors occurred.
Press any key to continue...
```

I try downloading the `Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi` with cmd:

```
vs_Enterprise.exe --layout c:\test --add Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi --lang en-US
```

But it gave me the error:

```
Download of 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel' succeeded using engine 'WebCl
ient'
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/9efbe138-ff
42-4deb-95c9-1d78cdc1f98b/356b789dfa97d11956dc1a1c1ec3abad20ef3ca4d4cd34fae9df18
489b34d6aa/VisualStudio.vsman' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Catalog load operation correlation: {"id":"f4ca2719-dc4d-46c0-b458-a3169a2d57db"
}
Layout operation correlation: {"id":"7780b16c-7775-4ac1-92b2-8a47537f7784"}
Planning 'Layout' operation
Error: The package 'Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi' is not recognized.
Error: Failed to plan for Layout.
Error: Setup completed with errors.
Error: The package 'Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi' is not recognized.
Press any key to continue...
```

But if I enter the url `https://aka.ms/AA9z5w0`, I can download the file `gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-win32.zip` so the link does work, but how can I add the final missing piece to my offline installer?

My question is how can I solve this error so that I can have the complete offline installer?

My current solution is create the folder `c:\vslayout\Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi,version=9.3.1` and put the file `gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-win32.zip` in it. But I wonder if this is the right way to solve it.

*Update:* My current solution works, after I manually download and put it into the offline installer, I re-run the cmd to verify the packages and it give me the OK result:

```
Total packages to download: 0
Starting 'UpdateLayout' operation
Setup completed successfully.
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Had the same issue, your solution worked for me (I was creating an offline installer of VS Community 2022). Why don't you create a new answer with your solution and mark it as accepted? So new people going through the same issue can easily spot the solution.

Comment: Just to note: the same happened in Russia. It seems that developer.arm.com has banned Russian IPs. Thus, I've used VPN and your workaround to get the package. Thanks a lot! It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error said:

```
Error: Package 'Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi,version=9.3.1' failed to download from '
https://aka.ms/AA9z5w0'.
```

So in Firefox browser, enter the url `https://aka.ms/AA9z5w0`, then I can download the file `gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-win32.zip`

Create the folder `c:\vslayout\Linux.GCC.arm_none_eabi,version=9.3.1` and put the file `gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-win32.zip` in it.

After I manually download and put it into the offline installer, I re-run the cmd `vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\vslayout --lang en-US` to verify the packages and it gives me the OK result:

```
Total packages to download: 0
Starting 'UpdateLayout' operation
Setup completed successfully.
Press any key to continue...
```

Success!!!

Answer (score 2):

I checked your command line(vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\vslayout --lang en-US) and it is good, without any error. Not sure, but the prompt error may be caused by Microsoft Server side or CDN provider.

In my mind there were some similar issues reported before, which also mentioned "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel…" or "Package XXXXX failed to download from XXXXX", like this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MicrosoftVisualStudioPerformanceProvid/1374924?space=8&q=Package+failed+to+download+from.+WebClient+download+failed%3A+The+request+was+aborted%3A+Cou+ld+not+create+SSL%2FTLS+secure+channel), and this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/upgrading-from-VS1691-to-VS1692-fail/1373149).

The solution you mentioned, maybe not a really "correct" solution, as this maybe a potential issue, but as you downloaded the package from the prompt link and it passed the verification, the installation should be good and complete.

Your solution is helpful and may benefit other forum members who meet the same/similar issue, so I just make a

**summary**:

Create a folder and name it with the name that error message mentioned, and then download the file/package from the link which error message prompt. Put it to this folder. Verify the installation by using command [--verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=optional%3A%20verify%20the%20contents%20of%20a%20layout.%20any%20corrupt%20or%20missing%20files%20are%20listed).